# Getting boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request exception

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to **download the log files that are present in S3 bucket using boto**. The reason behind not using s3cmd and some other tools is that I don't want my code to be dependent on some kind of software/tool so that others can also use my code directly and don't have to worry about downloading some other dependencies.

I am getting the following stack trace. I saw various related posts but none of them solved my problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 743, in main
*args, **kwargs
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 405, in execute
results['<local-only>'] = task.run(*args, **new_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 171, in run
return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/pgbadger/pgbadger_html.py", line 86, in dlogs
s3 = S3()
File "/pgbadger/pgbadger_html.py", line 46, in __init__
self.bucket = self._get_bucket(self.log_bucket)
File "/pgbadger/pgbadger_html.py", line 65, in _get_bucket
return self.s3_conn.get_bucket(bucket)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 471, in get_bucket
return self.head_bucket(bucket_name, headers=headers)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 518, in head_bucket
response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
```

I have seen the code and I don't know why I am getting this error. My code is as follows:

```
from fabric.api import task
from fabric.api import env

S3_LOG_BUCKET = BUCKET-NAME


class S3(object):
    s3_conn = None
    log_bucket = S3_LOG_BUCKET
    region = region
    bucket = None
    env.host_string = REGION-NAME

    def __init__(self):
        self._s3_connect()
        self.bucket = self._get_bucket(self.log_bucket)

    def _s3_connect(self):
        if not self.s3_conn:
            self.s3_conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region(
                self.region,
                aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            )
        if not self.s3_conn:
            raise ValueError('Invalid Region Name: {}'.format(region))

    def download_s3_logs(self):
        for l in self.bucket.list():
            key_string = str(l.key)
            l.get_contents_to_filename("/tempLogFiles/" + key_string)
            print l.key

    def _get_bucket(self, bucket):
        return self.s3_conn.get_bucket(bucket)


@task
def dlogs():
    s3 = S3()
    s3.download_s3_logs()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved:
In the S3-Log-Bucket, I was mentioning the entire path specific to my bucket.. Like I have my bucket and there are multiple folders in it. So I was mentioning the entire path to it but BOTO doesn't expect that to happen. Hence I just had to mention the bucket name only instead of mentioning the entire path.

Previously I was doing-->

```
log_bucket = Bucket/Inner Folder 1/Inner Folder 2/.../ which was wrong
```

Correct way of doing it-->

```
log_bucket = Bucket
```